# Sharpen on image with Action Script 3.0?

Tags: actionscript-3

Can I use AS3 sharpen on image? Found that seems to be can use a matrix. And how to use it?

```
a  b  a
b  c  b
a  b  a
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must specify the a positive value at the center and the negative edges.

```
sampleSprite.filter = [new ConvolutionFilterC, 3, 
[0, -1, 0, -1, 5, -1, 0, -1, 0])];
```

If you need to weaken the effect - to increase the value and applicability of the central divider

```
 sampleSprite.filter = [new ConvolutionFilterC, 3, 
 [O, -1, 0, -1, 10, -1, 0, -1, 0], 5)];
```

If it is necessary to enhance the effect, the central value decreases and increases around the values.

```
 sampleSprite.filter = [new ConvolutionFilterC, 3, 
 [O, -1, 0, -1, 1, -1, 0, -1, 0] -3)];
```

Read the book "ActionScript 3.0 Сookbook". It describes this question.

Answer (score 1):

I found this [page with some live filter examples](http://sakri.net/technology/flash/flex/convolution_filter/ConvolutionFilterExplorer.html).

```
    new ConvolutionFilter(3,3,new Array(0,-1,0,-1,7,-1,0,-1,0),3); //Stronger sharp
    new ConvolutionFilter(3,3,new Array(0,-1,0,-1,10,-1,0,-1,0),6); //Medium sharp
    new ConvolutionFilter(3,3,new Array(0,-1,0,-1,12,-1,0,-1,0),8); //Lower sharp
```